# Getting the top 3 count of database

Tags: php, mysql

I need a query to get the top 3 count from my database, but using max will just get the top first count from it. How do I get the top 3 count?

```
count

30
29
29
28
28
28
27
26
25

SELECT count FROM tableName WHERE count = max($count) LIMIT 30 //doesn't work because max only get the top first count.
```

**Expected Results**

```
30
29
29
28
28
28
```

Comment: Not clear please provide the original data and expected result and the logic behind top 3 counts.

Comment: ...@AbhikChakraborty What are you talking about? The original data is below count. Count is the colName. The expected result is in BOLD. And the logic behind top 3 count? Isn't that obvious? Instead of getting the top first count using max, you get the top 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subquery selects the highest 3 distinct values. In this case they are 30, 29 and 28 and the outer query selects all rows that have one of those counts.

```
select `count` from tablename
where `count` in (
    select distinct `count`
    from tablename
    order by `count` desc
    limit 3
)
```

By the way, `count` is a reserved word and you should try to avoid using it as a column name.

Comment: Nope. That will only get 30, 29, 29. Remember the expected result is 30, 29, 29, 28, 28, 28? And please don't say just use LIMIT 6, then, because you don't know how many rows there are. That's just an example, above.

Comment: @jessica no, it will get 30, 29, 29, 28, 28, 28

Comment: Ah, sorry. I saw 3 answers that gets 30,29,29 and I assume that no one knows what I was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT count FROM tableName order by count desc limit 3

I hope that it will help you

Comment: Nope. That will only get 30, 29, 29. Remember the expected result is 30, 29, 29, 28, 28, 28? And please don't say just use LIMIT 6, then, because you don't know how many rows there are. That's just an example, above.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you're asking for, but try the following:

```
SELECT `count`
FROM tableName
GROUP BY `count`
ORDER BY `count` DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Result:

```
30
29
28
```

If you need to know how many times each of those values occur, try:

```
SELECT `count`, COUNT(*) AS times
FROM tableName
GROUP BY `count`
ORDER BY `count` DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Result:

```
30, 1
29, 2
28, 3
```

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ef65/2)

Comment: Nope. That will only get 30, 29, 29. Remember the expected result is 30, 29, 29, 28, 28, 28? And please don't say just use LIMIT 6, then, because you don't know how many rows there are. That's just an example, above.

Comment: No, my first query will get 30, 29, 28.  See the SQLFiddle.  My second query provides the same information as your expected result, albeit in a different form.